# Looking for a long-distance (~1km) physical layer

Tags: ground, rs485

First of all, I have to say my knowledge on how networks work physically is limited. I am working on a project to interconnect farming equipment over fairly long distances, at a maximum of 1km, more or less. I looked at RS-485 but I don't entirely understand the need for a common ground, and I'm not really sure if it is needed or not. Basically, I am looking for the cheapest reliable way to connect this devices on a bus-like network over such long distances.

Is the common grounding needed? If so, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Would you consider wifi? 1km can be achieved with fairly low cost equipment. As an example, ubiquiti makes hardware that can do this.

Comment: If you're connecting farming equipment, does the equipment (like a combine or harvester) move? If so, a wired network like RS-485 has an obvious problem.

Comment: What minimum data rate is acceptable? One or many of? Order of acceptable max BOM cost for comms? 1 / 10 /100 ... $? |
 At eg 200 baud (Agh) using the relevant Bell standard of the long ago day you can get semi infinite range on wet string. Maybe not quite. But using copper telephone pairs I lonnnnnnnnnnnng ago hooked up a star network (out to x and back) of pairs in series to probably 10's of miles total and got solid copy at 200 bauds. Even semi informal RS232 adapted to your need may work well. |

Comment: RS485 needs loop V_extremes to lie inside limits BUT there are ways of doing this electronically without a 3rd wire

Comment: @mkeith No, wired is much better for this application. There is often no line of sight so WiFi will not reach.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast no, the equipment does not move.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm not sure, but 50kb/s would probably be acceptable, or maybe even less. All I really need is a physical layer that will support as many nodes as possible and will get the data from one point to another right most of the time. The protocols over the physical layer could tolerate for some failures, but if it's constantly failing, there's nothing they can do.

Comment: What about a high spot somewhere central that has line of sight to all the nodes? Wifi cannot be chewed up by the flail mower or tiller. Low cost 900 MHz units are available which tolerate some vegetation. I think it will be cheaper and more reliable than buried cable. 1km is a short hop for the long range wireless stuff. You can power it with battery and solar panel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!! For RS-485 network common grounding is needed. It is achieved by running a separate GND wires between all nodes. The RS-485 pair needs to be a twisted pair. And for these long distances you may want to consider the use of some type of shielding for the cable.

The common GND is needed to help maintain the common mode voltage between any two nodes to within the range needed to keep your receivers working. A normal range is something like -8V to +12V CM. You can get special transceiver chips with extended common mode voltage voltage range (i.e. TI's SN65HVD1785 family of parts) supports a range from -20V to +25V. But even with this you need to have a common GND wire.

You can operate your RS-485 network at these distances with good cables and proper types of terminations at rates in the neighborhood of 115.2K baud. But keep in mind that your 1 km distance should be the total cable distance and not the distance between multiple different nodes.

For successful design and deployment of RS-485 networks I strongly recommend that you read and comprehend these application note documents:

**Application Note 847 FAILSAFE Biasing of Differential Buses**

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla031/snla031.pdf

**AN-1057 Ten Ways to Bulletproof RS-485 Interfaces**

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla049b/snla049b.pdf

**B&B Electonics RS-422 and RS-485 Applications eBook**

http://www.bb-elec.com/Learning-Center/All-White-Papers/Serial/RS-422-and-RS-485-Applications-eBook/RS-422-RS-485-eBook-graphics-embedded.pdf

Comment: Alright, let's see if I have this clear. Say I have 3 devices, each 200 meters apart. That'd be 600m of cable, so it's enough. Each device has its power supply. Should I connect the ground output of each power supply together? Couldn't current flow between them, if there is a GPD?

Comment: @zyngawow - First off you need to study the data sheet for your RS-485 interface part. It should give guidance as to the length of cable at various data rates that the device can support. Second - with three devices 200 meters apart it takes a total of 400 meters cable not 600. Third - if each power supply is fully isolated from its line voltage then connecting each unit with a common GND wire should not result in any significant current flow between the devices. Lastly I have no idea what "GPD" is.

Comment: GPD is ground potential difference. So, basically, I should run a shielded cable with 2 twisted pairs inside, use one pair for data, and the other one for the common grounding, connecting all power supplies' GNDs together, and make sure the power supplies are isolated.

Comment: @zyngawow - Yes, make sure to connect all the GNDs together. It would be best if all the supplies are isolated. Also read the three application notes I added to the answer. These are the "known required reading" for using RS-485.

Answer (score 2):

A wireless solution is much easier to use and provides much more flexibility for later in terms of having additional RTUs. You would have to use a protocol that allows individual slave addressing in much the same way as having RTUs on an RS-485 loop.

There are lots of clever little boards:

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1km-wireless-transceiver-with-rs232-for_60151841507.html

or

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/433MHz-30mw-1km-wireless-transceiver_60024610908.html

Use a small tuned, high gain YAGI antenna pointed in the right direction and Bob, as they say, is your uncle. 100 mW should be more than enough for point to point comms at 1 km. If the units are not roughly in line, the base antenna becomes more of an issue but I'll leave it there. Some research into existing solutions might be worthwhile.

Good luck.

Comment: Ubiquiti makes decent and very affordable long distance wifi stuff also.